# How to get AJAX URL with Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to get the outgoing AJAX request URL using Selenium? For example, when I click a button, it generates a AJAX request to get some data. How can I use Python to determine that GET request URL?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: @JakeSteele I've been researching for a couple of hours and haven't been able to find any good leads, so I haven't had anything to try yet. It seems like it's possible in Java versions of Selenium and with other JS tools, but I need to do it in Python. So even if you just have some suggestions on the general direction that I should look that would be great!

Comment: You can try with browser mob proxy to capture outgoing or incoming requests.